# C# Поставить в соответствие элементу Button определенный элемент массива

Tags: c#, массивы, button

Есть двумерный массив arr[5,5]  и на форме 25 кнопок расположенных 5 на 5
Как сопоставить элемент этого массива определенной кнопке,то есть чтобы при нажатии на какую-то кнопку менялось значение элемента в массиве(или в соседних элементах)?
Другими словами я хочу как-то проиндексировать элемент button, чтобы можно было засунуть его в цикл

Comment: WPF или WinForms?

Comment: Использовать массив кнопок?

Comment: WindowsForms
Попробую с массивом кнопок,спасибо